# JavaScript naming and grouping

Tags: javascript, beginner, meteor

I'm fairly new to JavaScript. I would like some feedback on the naming and grouping of the following code. Is there any change that will make it more readable?

```
Template.documentPage.events({
  'click .hint-text': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var currentHintId = $(e.target).attr('id')
    Session.set('currentHintId', currentHintId)

    $('.hint-popup').show()
  },

  'click .hint-submit': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var currentHintId = Session.get('currentHintId')
    var popupInput = $('.hint-popup input').val()

    $('#' + currentHintId).text(popupInput)
    Documents.update(this._id, {$set: {content: $('.content').html()}}, function() {
      console.log('Saved.')
    })

    $('.hint-popup').hide()
    $('.hint-popup input').val('Enter text')
  }
})
```

Comment: Please post the full source code for the object. While this may be working code, it is incomplete.

Comment: @Greg Burghardt OK, I posted the whole thing. They are Meteor events: http://meteor.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start off, I can't see a single semicolon being used here. You should **always** close your statements with a semicolon.

Also I can't quite understand what you've done here:

```
'click .hint-text': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    var currentHintId = $(e.target).attr('id')
    Session.set('currentHintId', currentHintId)

    $('.hint-popup').show()
},
```

Is this a property in an object? If so why have you named it `'click .hint-text'`? Give it a proper name such as `togglePopup` or something along those lines to make it more obvious what it does. Now it's just confusing.

And for the other function you could name it `submit(whatever you're submitting)`.

If you included some additional markup it would help your question a bit.

Comment: The object is used in a method in some framework, where the property names are used to define what events should be bound. It's a bit strange way to write settings, but when you pick a framework you also get to use its odd design choises.

Comment: @Guffa Then the framework should really be a tag so we can understand what is going on.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I read this post about omitting semicolons by the author of Bootstrap: http://www.wordsbyf.at/2011/10/31/i-dont-write-javascript/ I wanted to find out whether it was true, whether something can go wrong if I didn't use semicolons. So far nothing had happened. My app works just fine.

Comment: @Chrillewoodz I included the framework and updated the code.

Comment: @janoChen: The danger in removing semi colons comes from logic errors introduced as a part of JavaScript minification. When semi colons are omitted, the newline character becomes the statement delimiter. When you remove newlines, you could accidentally change the logic.